# Trouble Executing a .cmd file during a PS-Session

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

Im trying to execute a .bat file remotely in a powershell script. The code in my script file looks something like this:

```
$server
$cred
# Both of these methods are strings pointing to the location of the scripts on the
# remote server ie. C:\Scripts\remoteMethod.cmd
$method1
$method2
$scriptArg

Enter-PSSession $server -Credential $cred
Invoke-Command {&$method1}
if($?)
{
    Invoke-Command {&$method2 $args} -ArgumentList $scriptArg
}
Exit-PSSession
```

But whenever I run it I get

> The term 'C:\Scripts\remoteMethod.cmd' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

This happens even if i switch around the order the methods are called in.

I found this question [Using Powershell's Invoke-Command to call a batch file with arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541809/using-powershells-invoke-command-to-call-a-batch-file-with-arguments) and have tried the accepted answers to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't have expected the $method1 and $method2 variables to be available inside the scriptblock for `Invoke-Command`.  Usually you would have to pass those in via the `-ArgumentList` parameter e.g.:

```
Invoke-Command {param($method, $arg) &$method $arg} -Arg $method2 $scriptArg
```

But it seems in your case the path to the CMD file is making it across the remote connection.  Try this to see if the problem is related to a modified ComSpec environment variable on the remote machine:

```
Invoke-Command {param($method, $arg) cmd.exe /c $method $arg} -Arg $method2, $scriptArg
```